# ScriptApp.newTrigger in Ads-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-ads-script

Is it possible to create an ads script that will create a time based ads-script trigger, similar to the App-script option?

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("TriggerName")
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(currTime + REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
    .create();
```

I saw a post from 2017:
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-scripts/c/iKBts0ojnYk?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

[Using scripts to make automated changes - Scheduling a script](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/188712?hl=en)

You can schedule the script in the script manager, which allows you to do something similar to `ScriptApp.newTrigger("TriggerName").timeBased()atHour(h).everyDays(1).create()`

I think there is no trigger builder function for Ads script.